# Null value in lambda WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, null

How can we avoid null exceptions when using Lambda queries? In the below code when `InstallationDateType` is null I get an exception. How do I tackle with this?

```
foreach (AvailableDate availableDate in installationDatesResponseRootObject.Response
              .InstallationDatesResponse
              .AvailableDates
              .Where(a => 
                  a.InstallationDateType.ToString().ToUpper() == Constants.InstallationDateTypeDish))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: You can check if it has value before you start your for loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Null-Conditional Operator `?.` introduced in C# 6.

In your example it would be

```
a.InstallationDateType?.ToString().ToUpper().Equals(Constants.InstallationDateTypeDish)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if installationDatesResponseRootObject, Response, InstallationDatesResponse, AvailableDates aren't nulls.
Then change your LINQ into this:

```
 installationDatesResponseRootObject.Response.InstallationDatesResponse.AvailableDates.Where(a => a.InstallationDateType!=null && a.InstallationDateType.ToString().ToUpper() == Constants.InstallationDateTypeDish))
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my comment, here is an example:

```
var items = installationDatesResponseRootObject.Response.InstallationDatesResponse.AvailableDates
    .Where(a => a.InstallationDateType?.ToString().ToUpper() == Constants.InstallationDateTypeDish);
if (items.Any())
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
          //Do something
    }
```

Note that this is only an example. There are better ways to check if the IEnumerable is empty or not.

Comment: This will still result in a `NullReferenceException` because if `InstallationDateType` is null then `.ToString()` will fail.

Comment: @ScottBamforth you're correct. Fixed my answer with help from slanto.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are called `.ToString()` on a `null` reference, so you need to check for this first.

There are a few different ways of checking. If you're using the latest C# then you're probably better off using the Null-Conditional Operator `?.` introduced in C# 6 as mentioned by slanto.

If you are using an older version of C# then you can just do it in your `Where` method as below.

```
foreach (AvailableDate availableDate in installationDatesResponseRootObject.Response.InstallationDatesResponse.AvailableDates.Where(a => a.InstallationDateType != null && a.InstallationDateType.ToString().ToUpper() == Constants.InstallationDateTypeDish))
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Hope that helps.